# How can I get from a list of characters representing a permutation to graphics showing the cycles?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, functional-style, permutation

I am trying to graphically represent cycles in various permutations of the alphabet, and have a question in two parts.

I have

```
cycles[r_] := Identity @@ PermutationCycles@
   (FirstPosition[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], #][[1]] & /@ Characters[r])

cyclesGraph[r_] := 
 Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[#, 0.1] &)] & /@ 
   Map[letter[#[[1]]] \[DirectedEdge] letter[#[[2]]] &, #, {2}] & @
      Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}] &, cycles[r], {1}]
```

so that

```
cyclesGraph["AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE"]
```

produces

[image]

Which is fine as far as as it goes but:

1. I have a lot of `Maps` and applications that seem messy to me and wonder whether there isn't a better idiom for processing my list of characters into cycles and from there into the list of edges expected by `Graph`.
2. While I need both of these functions, I also need an additional one that *combines* all the graphs into a single one, with the letters of the alphabet arranged evenly in sequence around the circumference, and each the edges for each cycle indicated in a different style (e.g color).

How can I do a better job of getting from a list of characters representing a permutation to cycle graphics, especially one that combines and distinguishes all cycles in a single figure?

Comment: `letter` is undefined

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [found it!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_%28message%29#/media/File:Wish_list.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not going to win a beauty contest, but you might get some ideas:

```
string = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE";    
rules[cycle_] := Thread[DirectedEdge[cycle, RotateLeft[cycle]]];
edges = MapIndexed[Style[#1, Thick, ColorData[2][#2[[1]]]] &, 
   rules /@ PermutationCycles[LetterNumber /@ Characters[string], Identity], {2}];
verts = PermutationCycles[LetterNumber /@ Characters[string], 
   Identity];
styles = Flatten@MapIndexed[# -> ColorData[2][#2[[1]]] &, verts, {2}];
coords = ({Cos[2 \[Pi]/26 #], Sin[2 \[Pi]/26 #]} & /@ Flatten@verts);

Graph[Flatten@edges, VertexCoordinates -> coords, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]], 
 VertexStyle -> styles, Background -> Gray,ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Of course one can get a bit "fancier" using [`EdgeShapeFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html):

```
drawLines[points_List] :=
 If[points[[1]] != points[[-1]], {Arrowheads[{0, .025, 0.025, .05}], 
   Arrow[BSplineCurve[{points[[1]], {0, 0}, points[[-1]]}, 
     SplineWeights -> {2, 3, 2}]]}, Opacity[0]]

Graph[Flatten@edges, VertexCoordinates -> coords, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[26] -> CharacterRange["A", "Z"]], 
 VertexStyle -> styles, EdgeShapeFunction -> (drawLines[#1] &), 
 ImageSize -> Large, Background -> Gray]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
s = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE";
pc = PermutationCycles[ToCharacterCode@s - 64] // First;
Graph[Flatten[Thread[# -> RotateRight@#] & /@ pc], 
      VertexLabels -> Table[i -> FromCharacterCode[i + 64], {i, Flatten@pc}], 
      ImagePadding -> 12]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps better:

```
pc = (PermutationCycles[ToCharacterCode@s - 64] // First) /. 
                                         x_?NumericQ :> FromCharacterCode[x + 64]
Graph[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], Flatten[Thread[# -> RotateRight@#] & /@ pc],
      VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 12, 
      VertexCoordinates -> ({Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi - 1/26, 2 Pi/26])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent. That nails the first part (my version is a mess!). Thoughts on the second part?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius There you go

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[cyclesF, edgesF]
cyclesF = Map[FromCharacterCode,
            64 + PermutationCycles[ToCharacterCode@# - 64][[1]], {-1}] &;
edgesF = Developer`PartitionMap[DirectedEdge @@ # &, #, 2, 1, {1, 1}] & /@
           cyclesF[#] &;

str = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE";
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Cyan, Yellow};
vl = cyclesF@str;
el = edgesF@str;
e = Join @@ (el);
v = DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ vl];
vc = GraphEmbedding[CompleteGraph[Length@v]];
estyle = Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[el -> colors]);
vstyle = Join @@ (Thread /@ Thread[vl -> colors]);

Graph[e, VertexSize -> .5, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 EdgeStyle -> estyle, VertexStyle -> vstyle, VertexCoordinates -> Thread[v -> vc]]
```

[image]

Or, use `HighlightGraph`:

```
g1 = Graph[e, VertexSize -> .5, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
          VertexCoordinates -> Thread[v -> vc]];

HighlightGraph[g1, 
 Flatten@{Thread[Style[##]] & @@@ Thread[vl -> colors], 
          Thread[Style[##]] & @@@ Thread[{el , colors}]}]
(* same picture *)
```